# In Azure App Insight, how to get properties of events tracked from App Center?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, visual-studio-app-center

I use App Center with a Xamarin.Forms mobile application.
I use App Center's Analytics, especially Events to log a lot of information.

In order to compute those informations, I use Azure App Insights.
I have configured the export from App Center to App Insight, it is working well.

My problem is, in App Insight, I can see Events, but I cannot see the properties of the Events.

For instance, from that doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/analytics/xamarin#custom-events
I am able to see the "Video clicked" event, but not the "Category" and the "FileName".
How can I have those informations in App Insight please ?

Also, is it possible to know a relation ship between each properties ? In other words, to group all properties by date and time they have been tracked ?

Thanks in advance :)

Here are two print screen to illustrate my question :
[image: App Center]

[image: Azure App Insights]

Comment: Not sure if it can help you, but you can give it a try by using Application Insights Analytics. Documents [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-analytics). You can use **customEvents 
| where timestamp >ago(90d)
| where name == "your custom event"**, to see if the properties can be fetched in the results.

Comment: Yes it works !! Thank you so much @IvanYang ! :) By fetching results, I can have Properties of each event, that is what I need

Comment: I post an answer for it, could you please help mark it as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query in Application Insights Analytics:

```
customEvents 
| where timestamp >ago(90d) 
| where name == "your custom event"
```

Then to see if the properties can be fetched in the results.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the event AND the properties, and want to query it, I wrote a blog article about it here:

https://auri.net/2023/07/03/querying-application-insights-for-appcenter-events-and-metadata-with-kusto-kql/

Here's an example query:

```
customEvents
| where name in ("Software Update: Succeeded")
| extend jsonData = tostring(parse_json(tostring(customDimensions.Properties)).['Model Number'])
| where jsonData in ("model1", "model2", "model3", "model4")
| summarize count() by jsonData
```

You can also just query for customDimensions.Properties to see which events you have and extend/filter based on those.